# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) --> favicon not loading

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am completing a course from coursera on bootstrap and was following along with the course, but the toggle button on the navigation bar of one of the webpages isn't working and displays error in the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I have the same code in the index.html (home page) and the button seems to be working perfectly in that, but in the aboutus.html it won't open the collapsed navigation options

Here are the codes:

aboutus.html --> the one with the error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: About Us</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <ol class="col-12 breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">About Us</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <h3>About Us</h3>
               <hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col col-sm-6 order-sm-last col-md-6">
                <h2>Our History</h2>
                <p>Started in 2010, Ristorante con Fusion quickly established itself as a culinary icon par excellence in Hong Kong. With its unique brand of world fusion cuisine that can be found nowhere else, it enjoys patronage from the A-list clientele in Hong Kong.  Featuring four of the best three-star Michelin chefs in the world, you never know what will arrive on your plate the next time you visit us.</p>
                <p>The restaurant traces its humble beginnings to <em>The Frying Pan</em>, a successful chain started by our CEO, Mr. Peter Pan, that featured for the first time the world's best cuisines in a pan.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
                <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
                <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which <em>The Frying Pan</em> became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural culinary connections.</p>
                <h3>Dhanasekaran Witherspoon <small>Chief Food Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, <em>Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays, pays!</em></p>
                <h3>Agumbe Tang <small>Chief Taste Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Blessed with the most discerning gustatory sense, Agumbe, our CTO, personally ensures that every dish that we serve meets his exacting tastes. Our chefs dread the tongue lashing that ensues if their dish does not meet his exacting standards. He lives by his motto, <em>You click only if you survive my lick.</em></p>
                <h3>Alberto Somayya <small>Executive Chef</small></h3>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. He says, <em>Put together the cuisines from the two craziest cultures, and you get a winning hit! Amma Mia!</em></p>
            </div>
       </div>

    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                   </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                        <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row justify-content-center">             
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-6 order-sm-last col-md">
                <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
                <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md">
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-6 order-sm-first col-md">
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                   </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                        <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row justify-content-center">             
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your links to bootstrap.min.css is not correct. Please go to bootstrap site to find the correct version of bootstrap.min.css links or download them into your project folders (and use correct reference links in html page). This should fix your issues.  [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing the script tags at the end of your aboutus page. Try adding these lines just before you close your body tag.

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked! If you wouldn't mind accepting this as the answer so others know this was the answer that would be great!